# Windows Server 2012 network shares are uncessibile for some machines

Tags: networking, network-shares, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012

I have a little problem with new installation of Windows Server 2012 and I can't figure aut any solution for it!

I had have Windows domain with two DC running on Windows Server 2003. Recently I demoted one of them and added quite new machine with Windows Server 2012. Then I have promoted this new server do DC, moved to it all AD services and roles (now I have 2 DC, one W2003, one W2012 and one W2003 standalone member server).

All works well, **dcdiag** do not return any errors, but folder shared on new server W2012 (including system shares) are not visible from both servers with W2003. Name of new W2012 server is properly translated into IP on both W2003 servers (both by IP and NetBIOS) but command "net view w2012_name" return error 64 ("the specified network name is no longer available"). At the same time, folder shared on W2012 machine are visible from clients computer (with W7 but not form XP). I know that it may be an issue with SMB 2.0 protocol which is unsupported on older OS, but it should then be negotiated to use SMB 1.0. I rather  don't want to disable SMB 2.0 at all.

I have already searched the web, but found nothing helpful. In the past in my network there was a server with the same name as new W2012 server, but for long time it doesn't exist and was deleted from domain many year ago.  Maybe somewhere in AD, there are any obsolete objects with this name, causing my problem? (How could I check this?)
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Stupid question but is the server and the clients on the same subnet? I have some clients on the same network but different subnet and sometimes need to use the ipaddress instead of server name

Comment: can you ping the server from the xp clients?

Comment: Sure, ale servers are on the same LAN, can ping each other and their names are properly resolved on all machines and there is no firewall issue (turning off temporarily all firewall didn't change anything). And yes, all server can bi pinged from XP

Comment: Update: I  recently discovered that option "Enable network discovery" is disabled in Network and Sharing Center. When I try to enable it, there is no error, but next time when I open Network and Sharing Center, this option is again disabled. A "computer browser" service is up and running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I managed to turn on network discovery - (accordig to this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2722035, I have just to start few services) and after reboot all works well!